# Change commit name - Github

Tags: github, command-line, commit, github-pages, git-commit

I need to know how I can change this commit name:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi)

Comment: I tried that but nothing change

Comment: Have you read https://help.github.com/en/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user? If so, please clearly explain what you're still confused about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least, try and change your `git config user.name` to what you want to see (assuming you are the one making those commits).
Then make a new commit, push and see that the commit name you have underlined has indeed changed.

If that applies, then you can [reset the author name for past commits if you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52993934/6309).
A `git push --force` will be required.